# Getting an image clipped from a larger document to be displayable in HTML / CSS with flow

Tags: html, css

I have a single PNG file with various graphics artifacts for my website, and I would like in the help to reference some of the symbols with the text inline.

Using CSS I am able to get a div or div/img which allows the section of the png file to display, but I can't get these images to flow in natural text.

I have an example where I have created an over-sized image which contains **A B C D** spaced 60 pixels apart.  I would like to produce text which looks a little like.

> When you want to use the **B** then you need to...

However all my attempts break the flow, and the graphic causes the text to break.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stack Overflow example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .imgB {
            object-position: -60px -0px;
            clip-path: polygon( 0px 0px, 60px 0px, 60px 60px, 0px 60px);
        }
        .divForSize {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .imgBFlow {
            object-position: -60px -0px;
            clip-path: polygon( 0px 0px, 60px 0px, 60px 60px, 0px 60px);
        }

        .divForSizeFlow {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display:inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>On its own image looks fine but is sized for the whole image</p>
    <img src="MVRE.png" class="imgB" />
    <p>Done</p>
    <p>Inside a div, I can get the space taken to be sized correctly</p>
    <div class="divForSize">
        <img src="MVRE.png" class="imgB" />
    </div>
    <p>done</p>
    <p>
        When you want to use the<nb/>
        <div class="divForSizeFlow">
            <img src="MVRE.png" class="imgBFlow" />
        </div>
        then you need to...
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Sample Image showing the issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply `display: inline-block` for your `.divForSizeFlow` instead of `inline`

because `block` element inside `inline` produces line break

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp